# How to Bind a property of a list with the rowindex of a datagrid WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a datagrid, in MVVM connected to a list of IENUMERABLE, I need to bind the rowindex of the rows of the datagrid to a property of the elements of the list (need to have this information in the viewmodel).

What's the best solution?

thanks

Comment: have you thought about using listviews? This would might be better for you.
[wpf](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/)

Comment: Why do you need the index? The simplest approach is to add a property to hold it and just use a for loop on your list to set it.

Comment: Thanks.. was my first choice.. i need to check a range of rows (im doing in the viewmodel) .. but the datagrid has to be single selection..  when i do sorting, the list of viewmodel is not ordered like the one on xaml .. so i  thought to pass the rowindex..

Comment: the datagrid would need a huge refactoring.. if possible i wanted to avoid it, thanks!

Comment: In which case why not add a bool property to your viewmodel. Bind to a checkbox column in datagrid. They check the ones they want to do whatever with. You select those with that property true.

Comment: i wanted to permit multiple check.., if the user hold shift key and click on a checkbox... all the rows before have to be checked

Comment: `IENUMERABLE` is it possible to change it to `list` or `ObservableCollection` ?and are u going to select multiple rows? are u using mvvm?

Comment: @Avinash i'm using MVVM , i cannot use multiple rows

Answer (score 1):

You can use binding to ICollection[int] in XAML.

```
<...
ItemsSource="{Binding MyIEnumerableSource}"
SelectedItem="{Binding MyIEnumerableSource[0]}" />

<...
Text="{Binding MyIEnumerableSource[0]}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You can do something like this let me know if ur facing any issue

```
 public Type SelectedItem
            {
                get { return selectedItem; }
                set
                {
                    selectedItem = value;
                    SelectedIndex= List.IndexOf(SelectedItem)+1;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved using @andy approach:

The simplest approach is to add a property to hold it and just use a for loop on your list to set it 
thank you very much!!